# How to display the contents of view while using iAd

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using the following code to display iAd with my view. but I am not able seeing my test Ads & content that I used in view.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, bounds.size.height, 0.0, 0.0)];
    _bannerView.delegate = self;


    sample *sampleClassObj=[[sample alloc]init];
    _navigationController =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:sampleClassObj];
    _navigationController.delegate = self;

    self.window.rootViewController = _navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    _currentController = nil;

//  self.currentController=(UIViewController<BannerViewContainer> *)viewController;

    return YES;
}
```

I have done necessary coding for basic iAd implementation.
Can anyone tell me please what is the mistake that i have done or just tell me the easiest way to implement an iAd in my project .

I am a beginner to iPhone developer so please tell me the step by step procedure to implement the iAd if u can't find the solution for my above question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I got the solution. No need to answer this question

Comment: Remove the question from stack over flow

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing the banner view like this (change the content size appropriately):

```
ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
```

Then add it to your root view controller like this:

```
[sampleClassObj.view addSubview:adView];
```